# Migrating EC2 t2.medium to t2.large ssh issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have 2 EC2 instances - one for staging and one for production. They have a fairly similar setup.

Since we need to scale (while still staying on EC2), I want to change the type of the production instance from `t2.medium` to `t2.large`. My course of actions would be:

1. Stop the machine
2. Change the type
3. Start the machine

Before doing this for `production`, I experimented for `staging` moving `t2.micro -> t2.medium -> t2.large -> t2.micro` - on all the steps the machine stayed accessible shortly after the change.

The `production` is lost for SSH whenever I switch it to `t2.large`. By this I mean that after I change to `t2.large`, it's not reachable anymore with a response:

```
ssh: connect to host ****.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

If I change it back to `t2.medium` - the SSH works again.

What might this unavailability be due to?

Comment: When an instance is stopped and started, it receives a different Public IP address. Are you sure you are connecting to the correct destination after Starting the instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I checked that, connecting to the proper IP address. I noticed though that the SSH doesn't work in a random manner, not depending on the type of the machine

Comment: `Connection refused` means that you successfully got through the network, but it didn't let you login. In contrast, if it takes a long time and then times-out, it is an indication of a networking problem, most likely due to Security Group settings.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein got it. maybe you have advice about what to look at in order to resolve it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my impression is that it's very random - when I restart the machine, it might become unavailable for SSH; if I keep restarting it, at some point it starts working again